# Oracle scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me in solving below scenario :
I/p

```
Name salary
Ram 200
Shyam 900
Rabi 700
Ram 600
Rabi 100
Shyam 300
```

O/p

```
Name. Salary
Ram 200
Ram 800
Shyam 900
Shyam 1200
Rabi 700
Rabi 800
```

How to do this using oracle sql query ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a cumulative sum:

```
select name, sum(salary) over (partition by name order by id) as cumesalary
from table t
order by name;
```

The `order by` is not exactly what your output is.  If ordering is important, please be more explicit about the rule for the ordering.

Also, this assumes that you have some sort of id or creation date to specify the ordering of the table.  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no inherent ordering.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that this works exactly as per your requirements.  And I guarantee excellent performance. ;)

```
select 'Ram' as "Name.", 200 as "Salary" from dual
union all
select 'Ram', 800 from dual
union all
select 'Shyam', 900 from dual
union all
select 'Shyam', 1200 from dual
union all
select 'Rabi', 700 from dual
union all
select 'Rabi', 800 from dual
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1652)